# The pages aren't found for an app

Tags: django

Main url file:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', include('myapp.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)

My app url file:

from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from mainapp import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index),
    url(r'^url1$', views.url1),
    url(r'^url2$', views.url2)
)
```

When I go to "/", it shows the `views.index` from my app fine. However, it says "Page not found (404)" for url1 and url2.

```
Using the URLconf defined in myproject.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^$
^admin/
The current URL, url1, didn't match any of these.
```

What's up with that?

Comment: @Etun, if the default page from my_app is being shown well, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are matching `'^$'`, which is an empty string, so your other urls are not called.

Try:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^', include('myapp.urls'))
)
```

Note that I changed the ordering. This is so that `myapp` will never override other, more specific urls like `admin`.

Comment: @Alasdair Good catch, I'm getting a bit rusty in django.

Answer (score 0):

r'^url1$'

^ means start here;
$ means end here.

so, it is an empty string. it does not make sense to put anything between like you did ^ ... $.

how about to try: r'^$', 'views.url1'),

?